# Can we use the same Machine Learning model for two categories of product of the same company?

Tags: machine-learning, model, prediction

Can we use the same prediction model for two categories of products for example Beauty and Healthcare of the same company? Also, can we use the same prediction model for the Healthcare products of two different companies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, it seems like the question is asking whether the same prediction model can be used for different categories of products within the same company or for similar categories of products across different companies.

Regarding the first part of the question, it is possible to use the same prediction model for different categories of products within the same company, but it might not be as effective as using a model that is specifically tailored to each category. This is because the characteristics and patterns of each category of products might be different, and using a single model might not capture all the nuances of each category.

For the second part of the question, it is more difficult to use the same prediction model for similar categories of products across different companies. This is because different companies might have different characteristics, such as different customer bases, pricing strategies, or product offerings. Additionally, each company might have their own unique data sets, making it challenging to use a single model across different companies.

In terms of applying this to healthcare and beauty products, it is possible to use a single prediction model if the products share similar characteristics or if there is significant overlap between the customer base. However, it might be more effective to use separate models that are tailored to the specific characteristics and patterns of each category. Additionally, as you mentioned, offering credit or other incentives to customers can also help drive sales in both categories.

ps...."Based on my experience, selling healthcare and beauty products together may be more effective for younger individuals who are paying for their own healthcare, rather than for Medicare members."

Answer (score 1):

**On the same company:**

Assuming that the data for the two categories is similar: yes, but you should either:

1. Train an instance of the model for each category, or;
2. Combine the data of the two categories for model training and evaluation and consider adding the category as a feature.

What I mean by the data of the two categories being similar is that they should have the same data fields / features. For example, if you are forecasting sales then you should know historical sales, inventory, etc. for products in both categories.

I would typically prefer the latter option (2) over the former (1) since your single model would then have effectively trained on more data. The benefit of (1) over (2) is that you can deploy a different for each category for scenarios where the data between those categories is significantly different.

**On using the same model for different companies:**

This depends on what you mean by same model, the legalities surrounding the data, what you do with your model, and what your agreements are with the companies the data is sourced from. I'm not a legal expert (and you should consider seeking legal advice if in doubt), but I believe commercial use of a model trained on private data owned by a company requires the legal consent of the company.

If by *same model* you mean the model architecture e.g. a Neural Network with X layers and Y activation functions, then this is fine. If what you mean is can you use a model which is trained on one company's data to forecast another, or whether you can combine company data to train a model (hyperparameter tuning included), then depending on what you are planning on doing with this model you may run into significant legal issues.